# How to edit orange parent project files in Android Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have what seems to be the usual AS/Gradle project structure, a parent project with a /build.gradle and a /settings.gradle the includes the subprojects, and subprojects inside with /Subproject1/build.gradle etc.

Now for whatever reason, any files that are not in a subproject are not editable in AS. They are marked as orange, as are all the files that are in the root directory of the project.

I'd like to know how to mark the files in the parent project as writable. This seems separate from the "Mark as Read-only/Mark as writable" option which uses a lock icon instead of orange coloring.

Here's a pic. 
[AS project screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Musc2.png)

In the project view you can see .gitignore and build.gradle at the bottom  highlighted as read-only, where was the subproject's files at the top are all white and editable. The tabs are also slightly orange-shaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was because the parent project's directory was a symlink, which the newer versions of AS seem to not like.